# how to display response.body in console when iam trying to display only half of the response.body is displaying

Tags: flutter, dart

Performing hot reload...
Reloaded 3 of 551 libraries in 363ms.

```
I/flutter ( 5392): {result: {user: {firstName: pineapple, lastName: appy, rating: 0, referalCode: 9d9101f5, referalBonus: 0, referredBy: null, latitude: null, longitude: null, studentRollNumber: null, collegeName: null, course: null, are_You_Student: false, goddess: true, id: 2a6349f7-d0e9-4911-9db2-b9a75db62b38, userName: pineapple, normalizedUserName: PINEAPPLE, email: pineapple12@gmail.com, normalizedEmail: PINEAPPLE12@GMAIL.COM, emailConfirmed: false, passwordHash: AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEIswXO3uL0FrPSh6t6NqqUkSw68rtKQzZ/TSKh+joKAisveJ7fdGINju74b2BBndjQ==, securityStamp: TUT2OG6ANMUJAQB76TTENOZUXKMR37SL, concurrencyStamp: 20951ab0-209f-450b-aa84-e2742af61e74, phoneNumber: 9866332266, phoneNumberConfirmed: false, twoFactorEnabled: false, lockoutEnd: 2019-05-23T10:09:53.331909+00:00, lockoutEnabled: true, accessFailedCount: 0}, userInfo: null, role: {userId: 2a6349f7-d0e9-4911-9db2-b9a75db62b38, roleId: 0d1df9a4-800b-499e-a3fe-462157916435}, roleName: Admin, activityRights: [{roleId: 0d1df9a4-800b-499e-a3fe-462157916435, activityRi
```

Performing hot reload...
Reloaded 4 of 552 libraries in 593ms.

```
E/flutter ( 5392): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
E/flutter ( 5392): #0      createPost (package:handiling_json_body/api.dart:23:14)
E/flutter ( 5392): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5392): #1      LoginformState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:handiling_json_body/login.dart:89:28)
E/flutter ( 5392): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1117:30)
E/flutter ( 5392): #3      LoginformState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:handiling_json_body/login.dart:83:27)
E/flutter ( 5392): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14)
E/flutter ( 5392): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:566:30)
E/flutter ( 5392): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:24)
E/flutter ( 5392): #7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:240:9)
E/flutter ( 5392): #8      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:211:7)
E/flutter ( 5392): #9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter ( 5392): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:225:20)
E/flutter ( 5392): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:199:22)
E/flutter ( 5392): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 5392): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter ( 5392): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter ( 5392): #15     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter ( 5392): #16     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter ( 5392): #17     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter ( 5392): #18     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:10)
E/flutter ( 5392): #19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:5)
E/flutter ( 5392):
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a description of your issue? Also, what is your code? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This answer is while assuming you are using the `http` package.

Add this import statement

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

convert your String response into a Map (or List) depending on what you receive as the response. From your output looks like you are receiving a Map.

So you can convert your response string to a Map

```
Map responseMap = json.decode(response.body)
responseMap.forEach((k, v) => print('$k: $v));
```

Not exactly what you asked for, but this let's you see the entire response body in an easy to read format.